# Label textvariable empty - Python 3.6 - High Sierra OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am having problems using `label.config(textvariable=texto)`.
As a result, it seems texto StringVar() is empty because 'TextoVariable' is not showing.

```
import tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk() 
texto = tk.StringVar(value='Texto inicial')
texto.set(value='TextoVariable')

tk.Label(root, text='Hola Mundo').pack(anchor='nw') 

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack(anchor='center')

tk.Label(root, text='Hola Saturno').pack(anchor='se')

label.config(bg='green', fg='blue', font=('Verdana',24))
label.config(textvariable=texto)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI4J3.png). Which is what I expect from the code. Do you see something different or do you expect something different?

Comment: I have something different. TextoVariable is not showed. It is showed as blank text.

Comment: That's weird, but since I can't reproduce it on Win7, I'm afraid I can't help you. Maybe someone on OSX can.

Comment: Maybe a shot in the dark, does specifying the master help? So like `texto = tk.StringVar(master=root, value='Texto inicial')` ?

Comment: Now it is working...........specifying -> master=root

Comment: That's nice, but to be honest I'm not completely sure why it doesn't work without specifying the master. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can chime in.

Comment: your code works fine for me on osx. Are you certain _this code_ doesn't work for you? The behavior sounds like you are creating more than once instance of `Tk`.

Comment: Yes of course. This code does not work for me. I am using Anaconda-Spyder.....There is no more code that I show you.