# Closing window (exit button/command+w) does not quit mainloop (Python 3.6 - Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to stop program when I close window using click on window exit button or command/control+w.
I thought it is automatically.
High Sierra + Python 3.6 + Tkinter 8.6

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
texto = tk.StringVar(master=root) 
texto.set("Un nuevo texto")

tk.Label(root, text="¡Hola mundo!").pack(anchor="nw")
label = tk.Label(root, text="¡Otra etiqueta!")
label.pack(anchor="center")
tk.Label(root, text="¡Última etiqueta!").pack(anchor="se")
label.config(bg="green", fg="blue", font=("Verdana",24))
label.config(textvariable=texto)

imagen = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, file="lena.png") 

tk.Label(root, image=imagen, bd=0).pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seeing that you also asked [this question that no one could reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50926565/3714930), the problem is not in your code. I'm guessing you use an IDE that doesn't work together with tkinter very well. Where do you run your code from?

Comment: I am using Anaconda-Spyder last version

Comment: @Javier: please [edit] your question to include that information. Unless you specify otherwise, we assume you're running the code using a standard version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your code from IDLE(python 3.6 64-bit). Close button worked for me.

Comment: I am using Anaconda-Spyder last version.

Comment: I would uninstall and reinstall spyder. If that doesn't solve your problem then I assume Anaconda-Spyder doesn't play well with tkinter. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder